# apply postgres function on an array without unnest

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres function called site_opened_on_date which take as input an id and a date. 
The function's signature looks like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION recntrek.site_opened_on_date(
site_id bigint,
in_date date DEFAULT (
now(
))::date)
RETURNS SETOF "TABLE(date date, opening_time time without time zone, closing_time time without time zone)"
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 5.0
STABLE 
ROWS 3.0
AS $function$
```

I want to apply this function on 7 days.
I have tried this:

```
SELECT (
SELECT t FROM site_opened_on_date(100520000101526, _d) t
)FROM unnest(ARRAY[ now(),
 now()+ INTERVAL '1 DAY',
 now()+ INTERVAL '2 DAY',
 now()+ INTERVAL '3 DAY',
 now()+ INTERVAL '4 DAY',
 now()+ INTERVAL '5 DAY',
 now()+ INTERVAL '6 DAY'
]::DATE[])  _d;
```

But I get the following error:  **more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**
This is due to the fact that the site_opened_on_date function can return more than one row for a date.
Anyone has an idea of a solution ? I would rather not write a new postgres function, I would prefer to find a way to apply my array to the existing function in a query.

Comment: it should also be possible to use a function param as array with `in_date date[]` in postgresql.. and call the function like `SELECT site_opened_on_date(100520000101526, ARRAY[ now(),
 now()+ INTERVAL '1 DAY',
 now()+ INTERVAL '2 DAY',
 now()+ INTERVAL '3 DAY',
 now()+ INTERVAL '4 DAY',
 now()+ INTERVAL '5 DAY',
 now()+ INTERVAL '6 DAY'
]::DATE[])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily generate a series of consecutive dates with the function [`generate_series(start, stop, step interval)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM generate_series(now(), now()+ '6 days', '1 day') as _d
CROSS JOIN LATERAL site_opened_on_date(100520000101526, _d::date) t
```

or

```
SELECT (site_opened_on_date(100520000101526, _d::date)).*
FROM generate_series(now(), now()+ '6 days', '1 day') as _d
```

Use

```
SELECT t.*
```

instead of

```
SELECT t
```

to get resulting rows in columns (instead of a single column with tuples).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use subquery. Just do:

```
SELECT
    (recntrek.site_opened_on_date(100520000101526, _d)).*
FROM
    unnest( ARRAY[
            now(),
            now()+ INTERVAL '1 DAY',
            now()+ INTERVAL '2 DAY',
            now()+ INTERVAL '3 DAY',
            now()+ INTERVAL '4 DAY',
            now()+ INTERVAL '5 DAY',
            now()+ INTERVAL '6 DAY'
        ]::DATE[]) _d;
```

See example [here](http://rextester.com/OPPHZ17003).

Comment: Thank you ! I don't get an error anymore. Is there a way I can receive also the column name (date, opening_time, closing_time) in my result ? I would like to have a chart as a result (with column names). Thanks!

Comment: Use `SELECT (recntrek.site_opened_on_date(100520000101526, _d)).* FROM ...` to get separate columns.